# Spark created part files outside partition folders

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I used the below PySpark code to perform partition wise initial load from a huge source table into AWS S3 delta lake.

```
df.repartition(partition_name).write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("replaceWhere", partition_condn).partitionBy(partition_name).save(deltaTargetPath)
```

partition_condn variable gets dynamically generated based on a loop. Should be something like: partition_condn = "my_partition_name in ('2020', '2021', '2022')"

To perform delta/incremental loads, I used merge statements in Spark SQL syntax.

**Problem**: I see some part parquet files outside the partition folders like below. Didn't notice if this is before or after the incremental load.

```
my_partition_name=2019/
my_partition_name=2020/
my_partition_name=2021/
my_partition_name=2022/
part-00000-xxxx-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00000-xyyy-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00001-zyyy-c000.snappy.parquet
part-00001-zzzy-c000.snappy.parquet
```

The below show partitions command returns: "SHOW PARTITIONS is not allowed on a table that is not partitioned: "

```
spark.sql("SHOW Partitions delta.`<delta table path>` ").show()
```

Since this is production, I cannot play around too much and would like to understand:

1. Why did spark create part parquet files outside the partition folders? Is this expected or was something wrong with the code
2. How can I ensure all the parquet files reside in their own partition folders?